# Calculation of length in QGIS

Tags: qgis, length

I am trying to calculate the length of lines, which were convatede before from gps to Shapefile (vector layer). I tried it with "feldrechner" (matrix calculator?) and the most time I got 0, or in the other times I got a very unrealistic result.

I also tried it with measurement of lines. There I got a good result. But I think, because of tracing the line by hand it is not so exact.

Does anybody know how I can get my exact length or/and area?

Both my results were:
e.g. this result (first way): 2.74556577576214e-07
In my other way I got in this case 35,555m.

Comment: What spatial reference is your data in? it sounds like your points are geographic and your trace is projected... if you want a distance in metres then project your points into a suitable coordinate system and then try matrix calculator again.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user be sure to take the [Tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour)

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson I think your comment is worth an answer. GPS data is geographic in most cases, so unsuitable for length calculation.

Comment: @Miro I doubt this is the duplicate, because the length is measured, but in a wrong projection.

Comment: @AndreJ I think you are probably right, but still I prefer to have it covered as part of How to find line length than just having here answer as one short line "Use appropriate projection/CRS."